# Chrome (& new Edge) not rendering Chinese characters with JQuery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I am trying to see why Chrome and Edge are not able to render Chinese text properly, though the same HTML file is able to render the text properly on Firefox.

Minimal repro content -

```html
<html>

<body>
    <script>    
      <copy-pasted script content from https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js>
    </script>
    <p>
        菩薩慈悲 Some test
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Observations till now are -

- If I copy paste the content of JQuery from https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js and paste it inline into the page for use, the Chinese characters break on Chrome.
- If I load JQuery from CDN using the JQuery's suggested snippet

  ```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  ```

  it works fine.
- Removing the script tag altogether and just keeping the `<p>` element in the body works fine.

Broken rendered text -
[image]

Properly rendered text -
[image]

Comment: I tested it in both Chrome and Chromium Edge but couldn't reproduce your problem, they can display Chinese characters correctly. Have you tried to set the <meta> element in header, which can specify the html document encoding format？Just like this: `<meta charset="utf-8"/>`

Comment: Thank you @XudongPeng, adding `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` in `<head>` fixed the issue!

Answer (score 1):

adding `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` in `<head>` fixed the issue!

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.